# Need to configure azure SAML authentication for a web application

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

I'm creating a CRM website with "Login with Microsoft" option using PHP, Laravel.

My clients wants to implement SAML authentication. When I look for official documentation, I found we need to configure SAML XML metadata in login page.

Does it means we need to create separate login page for each clients with their respective SAML XML metadata as we don't know which client is logging to the website?

Note: I'm new to Azure, SAML authentication and PHP.

Comment: Are you trying to implement https://simplesamlphp.org/ in php ?